# How to data transfer between external source and azure synapse analytics

Tags: python, azure, azure-synapse

I will get data from external sources(for example crm sources) and then this data send to azure synapse analytics as a table and I will use Python for ETL.  But I analyzed a lot of sites but I didn't find nice info so How can do it?

Comment: The standard approach would be to drop it in the data lake first, then it's super easy for Synapse to access, whether it be via external table, Synapse pipeline or Synapse notebook.

Answer (score 0):

If we have any kind of external table data with Synapse SQL, you can use external tables to read external data using dedicated SQL pool or serverless SQL pool.

Also, there will be two types of process based on the data source.

Hadoop and Native external tables are two type which are used to achieve the process of data transfer.

We can investigate detailed explanation from Microsoft [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-external-tables?tabs=hadoop).

We have [Python Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-manage-python-packages#:%7E:text=%20Manage%20Python%20libraries%20for%20Apache%20Spark%20in,pool%20level%20packages%2C%20you%20can%20also...%20More%20) for Apache Spark in Azure Synapse Analytics.

Python packages can be installed from repositories like PyPI and Conda-Forge by providing an environment specification file.

We have a databrick python activity

```
{
    "activity": {
        "name": "MyActivity",
        "description": "MyActivity description",
        "type": "DatabricksSparkPython",
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "MyDatabricksLinkedService",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "typeProperties": {
            "pythonFile": "dbfs:/docs/pi.py",
            "parameters": [
                "10"
            ],
            "libraries": [
                {
                    "pypi": {
                        "package": "tensorflow"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-databricks-python?context=/azure/synapse-analytics/context/context&tabs=synapse-analytics) builds on the data transformation activities, which presents a general overview of data transformation and the supported transformation activities.